# Sort product in research result in BO

Tags: magento2, search, sort, product-sorting

how can I change the default sorting order from the position to the order of the category ?

In my result, I have some product of the Category 2 that appeared before the Category 1 (probably because I've added second category after the second, and it displayes the last added products at first).

Knowing that I've added some product from the C1 during I was doing the C3.

I want to show C1, C2 and C3 in that order.

As you see I have a lot of product, so I can do this manually.

[image]

EDIT :

Programmaticaly, I've found this method in Magento/CatalogSearch/Block/Result

```
    /**
 * Set search available list orders
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = $this->catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders['relevance'] = __('Relevance');
    $this->getListBlock()->setAvailableOrders(
        $availableOrders
    )->setDefaultDirection(
        'desc'
    )->setDefaultSortBy(
        'relevance'
    );
    return $this;
}
```

I've changed this :

```
        $this->getListBlock()->setAvailableOrders(
        $availableOrders
    )->setDefaultDirection(
        'desc'
    )->setDefaultSortBy(
        'relevance'
    );
```

by this

```
        $this->getListBlock()->setAvailableOrders(
        $availableOrders
    )->setDefaultDirection(
        'desc'
    )->setDefaultSortBy(
        'category'
    );
```

But I don't know if it's a reliable solution. Any thoughts ?